# Carrying medicine from US to India for someone who asked for a help in Facebook

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, india, health, drugs

Someone wants to send medicine for his mother who is suffering with an autoimmune disease. He pinged me on Facebook and said he will provide a prescription and order medicine from Amazon to my home.

Is it okay for me to help him? This is my first time carrying medicine in travel is it okay for me to carry someone's medicine?

And also I am not sure if he will be giving me an original prescription or a photocopy since that person is not in my state.

I want to help someone who is suffering from a disease but I don't want to have any problems either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carrying medicines internationally for a friend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23421/carrying-medicines-internationally-for-a-friend) Not even for a friend - never mind a stranger. And be wary of taking *anything* that does not belong to you, or that you did not buy, or did not pack yourself.

Comment: If you're really desperate to help, but want to limit the risk to yourself, then mail it to him and let him deal with customs where he receives it.

Comment: @brhans still a risky proposition. If the medicine in question contains something illegal then it would be traced back to the OP. There's a reason someone is asking them to carry it instead of carrying it or mailing it themselves. It can't be good.

Comment: Maybe this person on FB should be reported to the police for suspicious behavior.

Comment: Alternative titles for this post ***"What is a drugs mule?"*** or "***I'm going to jail in India. What should I pack?***

Comment: “_Order medicine (for an auto-immune disease, supposedly not available in India) from Amazon_”? Mmmmmhhhhh.

Comment: If you were to agree to do this, you would probably receive a sealed Amazon branded box from somewhere, with instructions not to open it (probably because of some legitimate sounding bureaucratic reason), and you would have NO IDEA what was in the box. Could be anything. Probably something not actually from Amazon.

Answer (score 29):

Do not do it.

First of all, it is likely not legal to carry medication for someone else across a border.
Secondly, you do not know that what is delivered at your house is indeed medication or something that is even more not allowed across a border.

Too many people are in prison because they brought something for someone they knew across a border. You do not even know this guy, do not take that risk.

Answer (score 28):

No, it is absolutely not OK. Someone is asking you to be their [drug mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(smuggling)).